# Prove for Existence and Uniqueness of Linear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

---

*Is that a good prove? Am I missing something?*

---

Consider a system with n >= 1 linear equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
a_1 * x = B_1 \\
... \\
a_2 * x = B_2 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

in which $ a_i = (a_{i1} ,..., a_{in} )  ∈ R^n $ and $ B_i ∈ R (1 ≤ i ≤ n) $ in variables $  x = (x_1, . . . , x_n) $.

Furthermore, suppose that: $$ a_{ij} = 0 $$ for all  1 ≤ j < i ≤ n

(i) Suppose that $a_{ii} ≠ 0$ for all  1 ≤ i ≤ n. Prove that the system accepts one solution $x = (x_1 , ... , x_n ) ∈ R^n$ .

*(i) ANSWER*

For this I thought about proving by induction in n:

**Base Step:**

For n = 1:

$a_1 = (a_{11})$

$x = (x_1)$

So $a_1 * x_1 = B_1$

$x_1 = B_1 / a_1$

**Induction Step:**

$n ⇒ n+1$

*(Induction Hypothesis)* Let $x = (x_1, ... , x_n)$ be the existing solution set for the system of linear equation:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_1+a_{13}x_1...+a_{1n}x_n=B_1 \\ 
  0x_2+a_{22}x_2+a_{23}x_2...+a_{2n}x_n=B_2 \\ 
0x_3+ 0x_3 +a_{33}x_3...+a_{3n}x_n=B_3 \\
... \\
0x_n+ 0x_n + 0x_n...+a_{nn}x_n=B_n
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

for n+1 we have:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_1+a_{13}x_1...+a_{1n}x_n + a_{1n+1}x_{n+1}=B_1 \\ 
  0x_2+a_{22}x_2+a_{23}x_2...+a_{2n}x_n + a_{2n+1}x_{n+1}=B_2 \\ 
0x_3+ 0x_3 +a_{33}x_3...+a_{3n}x_n + a_{3n+1}x_{n+1}=B_3 \\
... \\
0x_n+ 0x_n + 0x_n...+a_{nn}x_n + a_{nn+1}x_{n+1}=B_n \\
0x_n+ 0x_n + 0x_n...+0x_n + a_{nn+1}x_{n+1}=B_{n+1}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

From the last equation, we have that:

$a_{nn+1}x_{n+1}=B_{n+1}$ So

$x_{n+1}=B_{n+1}/a_{nn+1}$

The first n equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_1+a_{13}x_1...+a_{1n}x_n =B_1 - a_{1n+1}x_{n+1} \\ 
  0x_2+a_{22}x_2+a_{23}x_2...+a_{2n}x_n =B_2 - a_{2n+1}x_{n+1} \\ 
0x_3+ 0x_3 +a_{33}x_3...+a_{3n}x_n =B_3 - a_{3n+1}x_{n+1} \\
... \\
0x_n+ 0x_n + 0x_n...+a_{nn}x_n =B_n - a_{nn+1}x_{n+1} \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

They all have a solution by the induction hypothesis

So, as we wish, it is proved by induction that the set of solutions exist.

Comment: It is a good proof.